# is sonar multi-module broken?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

trying to make a multi module project I dowloaded the samples in github: I use this folder 
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/multi-module/sonar-runner/java-sonar-runner-modules-own-configuration-file as a project base dir

In a command line in this folder, I type `/opt/sonar-runner/bin/sonnar-runner`

First thing I find is that **sonar-project.properties** has a property named **sonar.sources=src**, but executing throws

`Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: You must define mandatory properties: sources`

Then I correct this property with **sources=src** and runner execution finish, adds the project to my sonar server, but no code, modules or file is detected. It is like if all project is empty.

It is exactly the same with other examples and with my own project. No matter if is java, python...

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of Sonar Runner and/or Sonar. Please update to the latest versions (Sonar Runner 2.2 and Sonar 3.5.1).

Comment: How do I check the sonar version?